# Nested list comprehension

Tags: list, nested, list-comprehension

Can someone please help me to convert this code (which works well) to nested list comprehension? I'm stuck. Thank you.

```
corrected = []
    for misspelled in entries:
        shortest_dist = 1
        shortest_word = ''
        for word in correct_spellings:
            if word[0] == misspelled[0]:
                ng3_misspelled = set(nltk.ngrams(misspelled, n=3))
                ng3_word = set(nltk.ngrams(word, n=3))
                jd = nltk.jaccard_distance(ng3_misspelled, ng3_word)
                if jd < shortest_dist:
                    shortest_dist = jd
                    shortest_word = word
        corrected += [shortest_word]
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work as needed.

```
[word for word in correct_spellings 
    for misspelled in misspelled_entries
    if word[0] == misspelled[0] and 
    min([ nltk.jaccard_distance(set(nltk.ngrams(misspelled, n=3)), set(nltk.ngrams(word, n=3))) ])
]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work as needed"?

Comment: Well, in the full working code, 'correct_spellings' is a spelling database that I can compare misspelled words found in 'entries'. If the first letter of a misspelled word matches the first letter of a word in the database it calculates the Jaccard Distance of the pair. Then it keeps iterating through all pairs of matching first letters to find the pair with the shortest Jaccard Distance and returns this. But in the attempt I have tried at list comprehension it returns the Jaccard Distance of all pairs where the first letters match. I can see why this is happening but I can't improve it.